# How to get rid of space between navbar and picture?

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out how to remove this space from my navbar and the picture..

[image: White space between navbar and image.]

The CSS code I have for the navbar and the image is:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 0;
}

a:hover {
    color: black;
}

header {
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    margin: 3px 60px 0;
}

li {
    display: inline;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

nav {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#bikebanner {
    position: relative;
    left: 65px;
}
```

`#bikebanner` is the image id.

And the html goes like so:

```
<header>
    <img src="images/bicyclebanner.jpg" id="bikebanner" alt="People riding bikes." title="Biking">
    <h1 id="pagetitle"><a href="Lab04.html">Cycling Tours</a></h1>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="aboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#askUs">Ask Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#destinations">Destinations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#faq">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="#reviews">Reviews</a></li>
            <li><a href="#seminars">Seminars</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tripPrep">Trip Prep</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Looking for a universal fit as I have other things with white space between them as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding this to your css:

```
img{
 display:block;
}
```

img is of type inline-block which adds a little space which is hard to find.

setting it to block should fix it.

Comment: Thanks, no space now!

Answer (score 3):

what space you are talking about ?

Keep in mind h1 by default has white space around it

Comment: I want the nav to appear directly under the image, so the border touches it.

Comment: @Zettsyuk remove padding and margin from h1 should work

Comment: I guess I should update the image more.. There's a title overtop of the image higher up, didn't have anything to do with it though. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1):

This drives a lot of people crazy initially and the solution is not obvious, but images, lists and list items end up with a small space like this due to the font size inherited by or set on the `img` or `ul`. If you do nothing, the `img` and `ul` inherit the body font size (often 14px - 16px) with results in this 0.25rem (or 3.5px - 4px) space issue.

### Nav Items

There are two popular solutions:

1. Float your list items left and make sure that you add a `clearfix` to your `ul` or its container, or
2. My preferred solution: Set the font-size on the `ul` to 0 and then the font-size on the `li` to 1rem (or whatever).

So my CSS would look something like this:

```
ul {
  font-size: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

### Images

If you set the image to `display: block`, this would kill the space below the image. This comes with its own caveats as well. For example, if you want it centered after you switch it to `display: block;`, you'll need to set the side margins to `auto`. Something like this:

```
header img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I should've been more clear. I see it gets rid of the space between each selection, but I meant the space on the bottom of the image, above the nav bar. Thanks though, it makes it look cleaner so I guess you helped my future self out. :)

Comment: The image thing makes people crazy too - same idea. I'll update my answer so hang tight one second.

Comment: display: block; worked!

Answer (score 1):

every h1-h6 tag has a margin top and bottom by default. i think if you overwrite this in your css you have what you want.

```
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

look at this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zn7wtdLp/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `display:inline`. This treats the elements like text, so if you have

```
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
```

you have the problem you mentioned, because the linebreaks cause a space.
Try to put your list elements like this:

```
<li>...</li><li>...</li>
```

For other solutions see [here](https://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block)

Comment: Again, my fault for not being clearer! But this helps me in the future! Thanks!